# Check for HTML 5 localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

How to check for HTML 5 localStorage  compability of the users browser?

I have been using two checks:

```
    if (window.localStorage) {
       // localStorage works!
    }
```

and

```
    if (typeof(localStorage) != 'undefined') {
         // localStorage works!
    }
```

Also, I have seen a function online which uses an try/catch block to check whether localStorage can add a key/data pair, or throws an error.

Which of those three methods would you recommend, and are there any differences between the first and the second?

Comment: window.localstorage should be window.localStorage

Comment: Thanks. Didn't see that error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect if browser supports HTML5 Local Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214404/how-to-detect-if-browser-supports-html5-local-storage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@MathiasBynens has written a nice article about this, comparing different approaches:

http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/localstorage-pattern

Comment: Please insert a solution in your answer, not just a link.

Answer (score 3):

The following is the code [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com) ([code](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/storage/localstorage.js#L37)) uses for `localstorage`

```
tests['localstorage'] = function() {
    var mod = 'modernizr';
    try {
        localStorage.setItem(mod, mod);
        localStorage.removeItem(mod);
        return true;
    } catch(e) {
        return false;
    }
};
```

IMO this is pretty much the recommended way to check for it.

Comment: not the code used by Modernzir. Where does mod variable come from?

Comment: @AlessandroLendaro In essence it's still the same code Modernizr uses (I added the link to the respective code in the answer). As for `mod` actually it doesnt matter what value it has.

Comment: of course it doesn't matter but it should be declared for clarity, even if javascript allows undeclared variables

Answer (score 0):

Both are equivalent here. First is shorter and therefore more convenient. This method is used, for example, in [MDN code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#section_7) for adding `localStorage` imitation that uses cookies.