# how to check whether localstorage is available?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

W3Schools recommends (http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

```
if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Code for localStorage/sessionStorage.
} else {
    // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
}
```

to check whether a local storage is available in the browser.

I use the following

```
var l=localStorage!==null?localStorage:0;
if(l) { /*code for locale storage*/}
```

and was wondering whether this is sufficient and reliable on all browsers?

Thx I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @gilly3 thx, searching for the problem I somehow missed this question. However, I think your answer is better than the once from the old thread.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. [w3fools](http://www.w3fools.com/) – You seem to think that w3schools is associated with the w3c – they're not.
2. Use `window.localStorage`.  Without `window`, you'll get a `ReferenceError` in browsers that don't support `localStorage`.
3. Don't use `localStorage !== null`.  In non supporting browsers, `localStorage` will be `undefined`, not `null`.  The better operator would be `!= null`, but I wouldn't use a comparison operator at all.  You can just pass `window.localStorage` straight to the ternary operator (`l = window.localStorage ? localStorage : 0`), or better yet, use `||`:

```
var l = window.localStorage || 0;
```

**Edit:** Really, this is all you need:

```
if (window.localStorage) {
    // do stuff with localStorage
    // no need to use window anymore
}
```

Comment: so I don't need the try and catch part?

Comment: Usually the try catch is more than you need. It handles the case where some script has created a global variable called `localStorage`. As long as you are aware of what scripts are included in your page, you don't need the try catch. If, on the other hand, you are writing a library or plugin that will be included in other sites that are out of your control, then using the try catch technique is more reasonable.

Comment: Are `'localeStorage' in window` or `window.hasOwnProperty('localStorage')` also a good ways to check for availability?

Comment: @zanona - those would probably work fine for most cases.  They have some downsides that would only matter in obscure cases.  Personally, I find their extra verbosity unappealing.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to check this.

Just like in the answer here:
[How to detect if browser supports HTML5 Local Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214404/how-to-detect-if-browser-supports-html5-local-storage)

Comment: See [http://stackoverflow.com/a/16427747/3710490](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16427747/3710490)

Comment: Don't like to use any external library

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes browsers block the access to the localStorage, like when you are browsing in incognito mode or private mode and so on... So checking if the storage exists is not the best idea, because sometimes it exists, but is not accessible.

### You can use this function:

```
function storageON() {
    try {
        localStorage.setItem("__test", "data");
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    } 
    return true;
}

if (storageON()) { /* DO SOMETHING */ }
```

Comment: OK thx, I'm setting var defaults before the localstorage code and just gonna wrap my code using local storage in try and catch. Thx for the hint.

Comment: @MacroBonelli - Looks like Modernizr is also using the same method to check if `localStorage` exists. (You might want to add `.removeItem` to remove `__test` though)

Comment: This is not great because it does the try-catch every time `storageON` is called.

Comment: Yeah, and there's absolutely nothing wrong with it. Try catch is a damn statement, not the devil.