# JQuery - Remember open accordion state

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion, jquery-cookie

I currently have a jquery accordion that does exactly what I want, except for one thing. When I click on a link in the accordion panel to go to another page I would like the accordion to remain open at the same place (if possible) when I click the back button. The back button is an image that I've created and not the back button of the browser.

This is my jquery script:

```
<script>
 $(function() {
    $(".jquery-ui-accordion").accordion({
        autoHeight: false,
        collapsible: true,
        heightStyle: "content",
        active: false,
        animate: 300 // collapse will take 300ms
    });
    $('.jquery-ui-accordion h3').bind('click',function(){
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
            theOffset = $(self).offset();
            $('body,html').animate({ scrollTop: theOffset.top - 100 });
        }, 310); // ensure the collapse animation is done
    });
});
</script>
```

This is what's in my header:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

It opens and scrolls very nicely and if there's a long piece of text in a different accordion panel, the panel that was clicked on will jump into screen view.

I don't want to alter what it does currently, I just want to be able to add a remember state when I click the back button image.

I've read about `jquery` cookies but honestly would not even know where to start with that to include it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you don't need to support IE7, use localStorage

Comment: sorry total noob, no idea what localStorage is or how to use

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `localStorage` as shown below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var selectedIndex = localStorage.getItem("selected"),
            // If a valid item exits in localStorage use it, else use the default
            active = (selectedIndex >= 0) ? parseInt(selectedIndex) : false;
        console.log(active);
        $(".jquery-ui-accordion").accordion({
            active: active,
            autoHeight: false,
            collapsible: true,
            heightStyle: "content",
            animate: 300, // collapse will take 300ms,
            activate: function (event, ui) {
                if (ui.newHeader.length) // item opened
                    var index = $('.jquery-ui-accordion h3').index(ui.newHeader);
                if (index > -1)  // has a valid index
                    localStorage.setItem("selected", index);


            }
        });

        $('.jquery-ui-accordion h3').bind('click', function () {
            var self = this;
            setTimeout(function () {
                theOffset = $(self).offset();
                $('body,html').animate({
                    scrollTop: theOffset.top - 100
                });
            }, 310); // ensure the collapse animation is done
        });
    });
```

Don't forget to [check whether localStorage is supported or not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11214404/2333214) before using it though. You fallback to cookies doing the same thing.

Comment: I copied your script above and it didn't work. It actually defaulted all my accordion panels to an open state and then when I clicked on a link to another page and on return clicked my back arrow, it didn't take me back to where I currently was. I want the behaviour to mimic what the jquery.cookie.js does but I couldn't get the scroll top function to work so discarded it. Much appreciated in your help though.

Comment: I tested the above locally and it worked fine for me. How did you *"defaulted all accordion panels to an open state"*..? Can you create an online demo with whatever you've so far..? You should not exclude such information from question. If you come up with a different description that effectively means you've wasted the time of all those who attempted to answer, which is very disappointing. And what does `jquery.cookie.js` do..? Going forward, please proof read the question and make sure everything is captured in the description before posting.

Comment: I didn't default the accordions to an open state, your script above did it. I'm sorry if I'm not explaining properly, but I'll try again. Currently this is what my accordion does: 1. Click on link on main menu, goes to page with accordion. 2. Click on a panel in accordion, accordion opens and displays menu with links to other pages. 3. Click on one link in accordion panel, goes to another page. 4 Click on back arrow to return to accordion panel, all accordion menus now closed.

Comment: What I would like it to do is the same steps but in step 4 I would like the accordion panel that I opened previously to click on the link to be still open and at the same link I had clicked.

Answer (score -2):

You can create a flag and set it as `true` when the accordian is clicked.

On clicking Back button, check if the flag is set as true or false. If it is set as `true`, just trigger the click action for that selector.

```
$('.jquery-ui-accordion h3').trigger('click')
```

Comment: nope that didn't work and plus I don't want to take away my bind part as that's what's making my accordion jump to the top of the screen. To be honest I don't even know if I put it in the right place.