# How do I submit form to storage in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this for **js**:

```
function storingValue() {

   if (typeof (storage) ) != "undefined" {
       //store
       var fname= document.getElementById("fname");
       localStorage.setItem("fname",fname);

       document.getElementById("Form").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("username");
       document.write('<a href ="storage.html" > next page </a>");
   }else {

       document.getElementById("Form").innerHTML="Sorry, your browser does not support Web storage";    
  }
}
```

and I have this on my html :

```
<form name="Form" action="storage.html" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
```

my question is How do I output what I saved to another page? I know that it 
has something to do with `action=""`, but I'm not sure how
it works. Can I create another `html page` and link it?

Comment: You cannot set a DOM element into local storage. You need to turn the contents of your form into a String first.

Comment: Your JavaScript code seems to be having unmatched single/double quotes.

Comment: @Thilo how do I do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19952403/save-form-using-localstorage-html5