# How to populate INPUT fields after submitting when user goes back

Tags: javascript, php

I have 2 forms for a shopping cart. When they go back I would like the input fields to be filled with info they originally put in before submitting.

**1st** uses basic form fields to `submit` billing and shipping info.
**2nd** is used for CC info.  What I would like to do is in that second form have a BACK BTN that will populate all the fields from the first form with the data they entered.

I have a PHP variable $response with an array returning values, but I don't believe they are all included.  It brings back a token from PayPal.  I think that might be purposely for security reasons.  Perhaps I can store them locally in some JS variables?

I tried the below with no results:

```
<input name="BILLTOFIRSTNAME" id="billtofirstname_id" value="<?php echo $response['BILLTOFIRSTNAME'];?>"/>
```

Comment: either use local storage or get data from ajax call to repopulate

Comment: You would need to store them into a session or cookie, that loads code.

Comment: Ahh, ok. But will that only work if end user has cookies enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this in your first page -

```
session_start();
$data = array("input1"=>"value1","input2"=>"value2");
// store any data in this array
$_SESSION['data'] = $data;
```

Now if user returns to this page -

```
if(isset($_SESSION['data'])){
// check if data is available
$value1 = $_SESSION['data']['input1'];
}
else{
$value1 = '';
}
```

In your input's html add this -

```
<input name="input1" value="<?php echo $value1?>" />
```

Comment: This is great also I will try it out in a bit. Thanks

Comment: Hey @Devanshu could you elaborate a bit on this.  It is returning a value of "value1" & "value2" - But I would have thought your code $value1 = $_SESSION['data']['BILLTOFIRSTNAME'];   would replace it.  SO I guess 1st prob is how to make it not put "value1" in as initial val and 2nd why would it not replace?  Does it matter where in the code I place the PHP I.E. Before FORM, inside, or after?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here you can use local storage variable

```
    <button onclick="store()" type="button">first form submit</button>

<script  type="text/javascript">
  function store(){
     var billtofirstname_id= document.getElementById("billtofirstname_id");
     localStorage.setItem("billtofirstname_id", billtofirstname_id.value);
    }
</script>



<button onclick="back()" type="button"> Second form back button</button>

<script  type="text/javascript">
  function back(){
       document.getElementById('Id').value=localStorage.getItem("billtofirstname_id");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Excellent method.  I will give this a shot and PHP method @Devanshu mentioned.  Thanks

Comment: I am new to this.  What would be a good way to store all the fields like lastname, email, etc in an array or object to use with your above code?  Thanks

Comment: Both are easy and good,
for more help please look over this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19952403/save-form-using-localstorage-html5