# jQuery fallback when localStorage/sessionStorage is disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, web, token

I have a REST based service architecture. One service is used to login users. A successful login request results in a `auth_token` sent back to the web client.

I would like to store the token in `localStorage` which is working fine in most situations. However it is possible that the user disables localStorage or the browser is in private mode (as far as I know only an issue on Safari).

My question is: Is there any concept I can use as a fallback when `localStorage` is not available?

Is storing the token in the `window` variable an option?

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: what is the scope of `auth_token`? does this need to be valid for entire session?

Comment: Possibly duplicate, I see a similar post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427636/check-if-localstorage-is-available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout this link to find whether you have local storage enabled or not.

https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/localstorage-pattern

Also, for the fallback you can use `cookies` always.  Or even if the cookies is not enabled, the only way to support is by URL param.  Usually, in these cases people will show a warning message staing their Localstorage/Cookie should be enabled in order to work with their site.  Hope it helps .

Alternatively, you can store in `window.name` which will be carried over on one browser tab; if you open the same page on anther tab it wont be available.