# how do I hide an element in javascript if localstorage variable is true

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to hide a video when the page loads and keep the video shown after any link is pressed

this is my current code

```
var videoplayer = document.getElementById("videoplayerlayer");
var links       = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

if(localStorage !== 'undefined')
{
  console.log("localStorage exists")

  if(localStorage["vv"] == false)
  {
    videoplayer.style.display = "none";
    localStorage["vv"] = false;
  }
  else
  {
    for( i=0; i<links.length; i++ )
    {
      links[i].onclick = function()
      {
        localStorage["vv"] = true;
        videoplayer.style.display = "block";
        console.log(localStorage["vv"]);
      }
    }
  }
}
else
{
  localStorage["vv"] == false;
}
```

Comment: use `localStorage.getItem('vv')` and `localStorage.setItem('vv', "true")`

Comment: Your logic is flawed. You check your localstorage entry for "false" and then set it to false. It will never become true.

Comment: @TamilSelvanC: `[]` access is defined for `localStorage`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks, I learned this now only

Comment: @TamilSelvanC: Happy to help. `localStorage.getItem("foo")`, `localStorage["foo"]`, and `localStorage.foo` all access the `foo` item. :-) You had to use `setItem` and `getItem` with polyfills, but these days you don't need polyfills, pretty much everything has `localStorage`.

Answer (score 5):

`localStorage` only holds **strings**. `localStorage["vv"] = false;` stores the **string** `"false"`, which is not falsy.

Normally I store JSON and parse it. That's probably overkill here, though, just store `"Y"` or `"N"` as the flag and check that:

```
var videoplayer = document.getElementById("videoplayerlayer");
var links       = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

if (typeof localStorage !== 'undefined')
//  ^^^^^^ Note 2
{
  console.log("localStorage exists")

  if(localStorage["vv"] == "N")
  {
    videoplayer.style.display = "none";
    // No need, it's already stored - localStorage["vv"] = false;
  }
  else
  {
    for( var i=0; i<links.length; i++ )
    //   ^^^^---- Note 1
    {
      links[i].onclick = function()
      {
        localStorage["vv"] = "Y";
        videoplayer.style.display = "block";
      }
    }
  }
}
/* You don't want this, it'll throw an error, since we know `localStorage` is falsy
else
{
  localStorage["vv"] == false;
}
*/
```

**However**, nothing in the logic reasonably sets `localStorage["vv"]` to `"N"` (the one assignment that was there was in a branch where it's **already** there). You'll need to add something to set it, unless you want to default to hiding the video player and **only** show it when `localStorage["vv"]` is `"Y"` (or if local storage isn't accessible).

For instance, this hides the player and only shows it if the flag is `"Y"` on load or one of those links is clicked:

```
var videoplayer = document.getElementById("videoplayerlayer");
var links       = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

if (typeof localStorage !== "undefined") {
    if (localStorage.vv !== "Y") {
        videoplayer.style.display = "none";
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
    {
      links[i].onclick = function()
      {
        localStorage["vv"] = "Y";
        videoplayer.style.display = "block";
      };
    }
}
```

---

Note 1: Your code was falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) *(that's a post on my anemic little blog)*. Be sure to declare your variables. See the `"Note"` comment above.

---

Note 2: Your check for whether you can use local storage was incorrect. I've updated it to what you probably meant above, but see [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427636/check-if-localstorage-is-available) for more thorough checks you'll want to use.

---

Note 3: I would recommend using modern event handling rather than setting `onclick`.

Comment: T.J I've seen a lot of your awesome straight answers on a lot of posts before you're a life saver..
Thank you for the clarifications !

Answer (score 0):

Below code can help you

```
$get('<%= AnchorId.ClientID %>').click(function(){
                  if(localStorage !== 'undefined'){
                         if(localStorage == false)
                          {
                            $get('<%= videoplayerlayer.ClientID %>').hide();
                            localStorage["vv"] = false;
                          }
                       else
                       {
                          $get('<%= videoplayerlayer.ClientID %>').show()
                          localStorage["vv"] = true;
                       }
                  }

            });
```